# How do I calculate PERT stddev if I use custom weight factors?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean

According to (for example) http://tynerblain.com/blog/2006/04/13/foundation-series-basic-pert-estimate-tutorial/, the PERT mean estimate is

$$\text{meanA}=(\text{optimistic}\ +\ 4 \times \text{likely}\ +\ \text{pessimistic})/6$$

I understand I can use "custom" weight factors for the basic estimates. For example, I could say I weight the optimistic estimate by a factor of 2. Then, of course, the divisor would not be 6, but 7:

$$\text{meanB}= (2 \times \text{optimistic}\ +\ 4 \times \text{likely}\ +\ \text{pessimistic})/7$$

Now a PERT estimate includes an approximation of the standard deviation. With the widely used weights of 1:4:1, the stddev is approximately

$$\text{stdevA}=(\text{pessimistic}\ –\ \text{optimistic})/6$$

I am not sure where the 6 comes from, and I think this is my question.

I am wondering about this because if I use the weights from $\text{meanB}$, for example 2:4:1, which divisor would I use for approximating the stddev? Still 6? Or 7?

Comment: This seems to be the only SE site where newbies get downvotes, and don't get hints why, or what they can improve...you feel better now? :-(

Comment: Oh, it's not the only one. I think your last paragraph says that you haven't read the FAQ carefully and you're even aware of that. Also, I think people really prefer the MathJax over what appears to be some kind of psuedocode or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean and sd calculations you give are used in PERT [three-point estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-point_estimation).

They might be regarded as based on either assuming particular cases of a 
four-parameter [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Project_management:_task_cost_and_schedule_modeling) 
or a particular *double triangular** distribution, such that the median 
and mode coincide.

* The double triangular has a density consisting of two triangles back-to-back (with a discontinuity at the mode). The general case has probability $p$ in the left triangle and $(1-p)$ in the right, but in the particular one discussed above, $p=0.5$

The values given for calculating the mean and sd are based only on the three specified values.  In the case of the double triangular with equal probability in both halves, the given mean is right, but I haven't checked whether the sd estimate makes sense (I believe it's based on a rough approximation).

To derive a suitable sd estimate for your differently weighted average, you'd need some basis on which the weighted average 
was a suitable way to approximate the distribution's mean and then obtain a suitable sd estimate from that same basis.

I think you might perhaps be able to choose a different beta or perhaps some other distribution so as to make your weighted mean work and then base an estimate of standard deviation off whichever distribution you ended up with. (No double triangular will produce relative weights of 2,4,1.)

Comment: What's enough to know is "No double triangular will produce relative weights of 2,4,1". Of course. Thanks!

Comment: You could get 2,6,1 though.